# issue to create physical DB's from DBML files?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

hi I have recently received a project file from a different company for setup in our company.
The project has all the data and runs fine, however there are no Databases supplied with it. by looking a the connections strings i can say they did use SQL dbs as back end. Now i can see the DBML files in the project files but no physical databases.
Is there a easy way to create DB from DBML files? OR i have to go back to the provider for further info of DB files? please advise

Answer (score 0):

You can

- either create a script for newly created database,
- or rightclick on database project and choose "Deploy"